# `find()` undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little jquery function:

```
$.each($('#TableBody tr:gt(0)'), function(index, element){
    element.find('td').last().html($('<span/>', {class: "input-group-addon", text: 'Auswählen'}));
});
```

Somehow i get this error in the first line:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I tried some things in the console to fix this problem! But somehow nothing worked!

Now i hope you can help me! JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3C98M/

Thanks

Comment: You haven't included jQuery in your JSFiddle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`element` is not a jQuery object, the second argument of the `$.each` function returns the native DOM node

```
$.each($('#TableBody tr:gt(0)'), function(index, element){
    $(element).find('td').last().html($('<span/>', {"class": "input-group-addon", text: 'Auswählen'}));
});
```

Also note that `class` is a reserved keyword in javascript and should be quoted.
It could also be written

```
$('#TableBody tr:gt(0)').each(function(index, element) {
      $(element).find('td').last().html(
          $('<span/>', {
              "class" : "input-group-addon", 
              text    : 'Auswählen'
          })
      );
});
```

which is more readable IMO.

Comment: Oh! I knew iv omitted something!! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Surround element with `$(...)` to work

```
$(element).find('td:last')....
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `element` with `$()` like the adeneo's answer or simply using `this`:

```
$('#TableBody tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td:last').html($('<span/>', {
            "class" : "input-group-addon",
            text : 'Auswählen'
        }));
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not the answer to question of John Smith (very generic name by the way) but it hopefully will be relevant to users looking for the solution to the 'X is not a function' javascript error (for which this post is the top result).

It can be, that if you are loading multiple Javascript libraries, $ (shortcut for jQuery) get's overridden.

You could use:

```
 jQuery(element).find('td:last')....
```

Instead of

```
 $(element).find('td:last')....
```

To solve this (or remove the library that overrides jQuery).

Source: http://codeimpossible.com/2010/01/13/solving-document-ready-is-not-a-function-and-other-problems/